# Age control in Facebook audience network ads

Tags: android, facebook, ads, facebook-audience-network, facebook-monetization-manager

I recently started using Facebook audience network for monetization in my android app ( I used to use AdMob).
I just have one problem, my app's age rating on google play is +3 , however I can't find a way in the monetization manager to block mature ads and only show ads that are suitable for all ages , it
just says the app is +13 with no option to change it.
On Audience network site I found this :

> If your app or service is Mixed Audience without an Age Gate, then you may use the Facebook Audience Network SDKs only if you set the setMixedAudience flag for all users. When an app or service tells Facebook that the setMixedAudience flag is set in the Audience Network SDK, Facebook will only serve ads to non-United States users of that app through the Audience Network services.

Setting the "setMixedAudience" to true seems to do the job BUT "United States users" are the majority of my app users and surely I don't want to block ads from showing to them.
Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: _"If your app or service is Mixed Audience without an Age Gate"_ - simple boolean logic would say that you'd need to implement an Age Gate then, right?

Comment: That may work but it's definitely not an option, as I said it's +3 simple app and it will be creepy to ask users to give there birthday informations just because I want to show ads, thank you for your reply.

Comment: And showing ads to 3-year olds is not creepy?

Comment: No, not if ads were complying to this age content rating categories, which is called 'G' and literally means +3 or (general audience)